# Testing GLMM residuals against specific families and link functions (R)

Tags: distributions, residuals, glmm, inverse-gaussian-distribution

When running a GLMM in R with `family=gaussian` and `link=identity`, it's easy enough to test whether normality and homoscedasticity of the residuals have been achieved (`qqnorm` plots and shapiro-wilks tests for normality and residuals vs. fitted plots for homoscedasticity). But what process should I use to test assumptions have been met when using a non-gaussian family and a non-identity link?

I'm mostly interested in how to test to see if the residuals are consistent with an inverse gaussian family and log-link, but how to assess for a gamma distribution might also be useful.

Here is a histogram of my GLMM residuals when I used an inverse gaussian family and log-link in case it helps at all: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YDjg.png

From what I've found, it sounds like `qqPlot` from the car package might be useful, but I'm not sure how to go about choosing shape parameters and such like. As well, that only accounts for the distribution I specified..not the link function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you can find an answer that applies to GLMs, it should also apply reasonably well to GLMMs, because if you condition on the conditional modes ("random effects"/"BLUPs"), GLMMs are the same as GLMs. So you're really looking for adequacy-of-link (Pregibon 1980) and adequacy-of-distribution (Augustin et al. *Comp Stat & Data Analysis* 2012) tests/plots that can easily be implemented for GLMMs.

Comment: one other possibility is to create parametric bootstrap/posterior predictive simulations of residual distributions and compare them against yours.

Comment: Ben's suggestion is implemented in https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/index.html